# How to complete is_rest() function on CS50 music exercise

Tags: c, cs50

While I was working on CS50 pset3 music exercise (that is explained one part of the exercise below). I come up with some questions:

is_rest()

Complete the implementation of is_rest in helpers.c. Recall that blank lines represent rests in our machine-readable format. And recall that synthesize will call this function in order to determine if one of the lines a user has typed in is indeed blank.

What does it mean for a line to be blank? To answer that question, start by looking at cs50.h itself, wherein get_string is documented:

https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h

PS: I checked the link but couldn't find / understand.

What do the comments atop get_string say that the function returns if a user simply hits Enter, thereby inputting only a "line ending" (i.e., \n)?

When is_rest is subsequently passed such a string, s, how should it (nay, you!) recognize as much?

My questions are:

Why do you thing that code is not working clearly ?

```
// Determines whether a string represents a rest
 bool is_rest(string s)
 {

    if (s == "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but this one works clearly :

```
bool is_rest(string s)
{
    if(s[0] == '\0')
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is the difference between the methods that are used on both cases ?

On the other hand, Can someone explain me the difference between `""` and `'\0'`

Comment: `==` doesn't work for strings. You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: operator == is valid if by `string` is meant `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

Update:

As noted by @Mark Benningfield, `string` is only alias for char*. In this case you can't compare it directly but you need to use strcmp() function.

expression `s==""` compares if s points to the same address like `""`, but not if s has the same content like "".

On the other hand expression `s[0]=='\0'` you're accessing first character of string `s` and testing if contains `\0`.

Because of that second expression is correct and first one not.

Comment: `string` in this case refers to the CS50 type alias for a `char*`, NOT to the C++ `std::string` class.